# SwiftUI - Picker/Radio Buttons - iOS equivalents of .radioGroup and .horizontalRadioGroupLayout()?

Tags: swiftui, radio-button, picker

I need to add some Radio Buttons to my App. Has this been removed in SwiftUI? There are lots of posts of people cutting their own Radio Buttons but can't believe something this fundamental doesn't exist, somehow?

Previous sample code would have been like:

```
    VStack(spacing: 20) {
        Picker(selection: $selected, label: Text("Favorite Fruit")) {
            Text("Apple").tag(1)
            Text("Orange").tag(2)
            Text("Banana").tag(3)
            Text("Kiwi").tag(4)
        }
        .pickerStyle(.radioGroup)
        .horizontalRadioGroupLayout()
    }
```

n.b .pickerStyle(.radioGroup) & .horizontalRadioGroupLayout() are not current iOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    .pickerStyle(.radioGroup)
    .horizontalRadioGroupLayout()
```

Are only for `macOS 10.15+`

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/horizontalradiogrouplayout()

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/pickerstyle/radiogroup

To support iOS you have to create your own.

Comment: That explains everything  :-) = ;-(